# Characterization of the Hamiltonian's spectrum in quantum mechanics

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

This is basically the same question I made on physics stack exchange [The spectrum of the Hamiltonian in quantum mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/755432/the-spectrum-of-the-hamiltonian-in-quantum-mechanics?noredirect=1#comment1693390_755432), but I got no answers so far and decided to move it to mathoverflow with some minor modifications.

The original question goes like this. Consider the Hilbert space $\mathscr{H} = L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ and a Hamiltonian:
$$H = -\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}\Delta + V(x)$$
for some potential function $V$. States of well-defined energy $E$ are obtained by means of the Schrödinger equation:
$$H\psi(x) = -\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}\Delta\psi(x) + V(x)\psi(x) = E\psi(x). \tag{1}\label{1}$$
With some boundary condition on the function $\psi(x)$. In the physics literature, we often see the following characterization:

- If $E \le \lim_{|x|\to \infty}V(x)$, the solution of (\ref{1}) is called a bound state and the associate eigenvalues that admit nonzero solutions form a *discrete* set.
- If $E > \lim_{|x|\to \infty}V(x)$, the solution of (\ref{1}) is called a scattering state and the associate eigenvalues that admit nonzero solutions form a *continuous* set.

Now, define the *discrete spectrum* of $H$ by:
$$\sigma_{d}(H) := \{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}: \mbox{$\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $H$ with finite multiplicity}\}$$
and its *essential spectrum* by $\sigma_{ess}(H) := \sigma(H)\setminus \sigma_{d}(H)$, with $\sigma(H)$ denoting spectrum of $H$. It seems to me that the above two conditions can be translated as:

- A state $\psi \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ is a bound state iff $H\psi(x) = E\psi(x)$, with $E \in \sigma_{d}(H)$.
- A state $\psi$ is a scattering state for $H$ iff $H\psi(x) = E\psi(x)$ with $E \in \sigma_{ess}(H)$.

Hence, it seems that the study of the discrete and essential spectrum of $H$ *completely characterizes its bound and scattering states*.

On the other hand, we can also define the *pure point spectrum* $\sigma_{pp}(H)$, the *absolutely continuous spectrum* $\sigma_{ac}(H)$ and the *singular spectrum* $\sigma_{s}(H)$ of $H$ by means of the [Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/755432/the-spectrum-of-the-hamiltonian-in-quantum-mechanics?noredirect=1#comment1693390_755432).

In mathematics books, one is usually interested in the characterization of these three spectrum. So, my question is: if the above analysis is correct, what is the point of analyzing these three other spectrum, if all relevant physical information seems to be concentrated on the discrete and essential spectrum? I mean, if I prove that $\sigma_{ac}(H)\cup \sigma_{s}(H) = \emptyset$, then the spectrum of $H$ consists only of eigenvalues and the study of the Schrödinger equation tell us all we need to know about the spectrum of $H$. That's fine to me. But otherwise, what is the physical relevance of $\sigma_{ac}(H)$ and $\sigma_{s}(H)$ when this is *not* the case?

**Add:** I want to add just one small point to the original question. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_of_spectrum_(functional_analysis)) says that absolutely continuous spectrum physically corresponds to free states whilst pure point spectrum corresponds to bound states. This would partly answer my question, but it does not seem to be in agreement with the above discussion often found in physics textbooks, since a scattering or free state is also an eigenvector of $H$, so its associated eigenvectors should be in $\sigma_{pp}(H)$ as far as I understand. In addition, even if this was the case and I am just misunderstanding something, I still do not understand why one needs these two kinds of characterization of the spectrum, since the $\sigma_{d}(H)$ and $\sigma_{ess}(H)$ seem enough to address the question of whether a state is bound or not, and how states evolve in time.

Comment: From a mathematical point of view, you got many of the small details wrong. Chapter 13 of my functional analysis lecture notes discusses many of these issues, see here: https://math.ou.edu/~cremling/teaching/ln.html

Comment: A classic physical interpretation of the relevance of the Lebesgue decomposition is the RAGE theorem. In Teschl's "Mathematical Methods of Quantum Mechanics" (which is freely available on his website) this can be found in Chapter 5. // There's one mistake I'd like to point out: scattering states (especially as you defined it) are not $L^2$ functions (especially easy to see when you work on Schrodinger operators on the line with good potentials), so they don't have a corresponding eigenvector.

Comment: @ChristianRemling thank you for the lecture notes. I skimmed over it and they look really well-written. It seems, however, that you only consider the $\sigma_{pp}(H)$, $\sigma_{ac}(H)$ and $\sigma_{s}(H)$ decomposition, right? This is somehow part of the question because, as you do not consider the essential and discrete spectrum in your notes, many other references only consider these, instead of the former. I still do not understand why choosing one decomposition over the other one. Do they serve for different purposes?

Comment: @MathMath: That's because $\sigma_{d},\sigma_{ess}$ (unlike $\sigma_{ac}$ etc.) are not directly related to dynamical behavior, other than the trivial remark that the points in $\sigma_d$ are eigenvalues, so correspond to bound states. However, in $\sigma_{ess}$, all three types of spectrum (pp, sc, ac) are possible. The $\sigma_d$, $\sigma_{ess}$ decomposition indeed mainly has another purpose: $\sigma_{ess}$ is stable under compact perturbations. (Your definition of $\sigma_d$ is not quite the usual one: the discrete spectrum contains the *isolated* eigenvalues of finite multiplicity.)

Comment: I assume you have a physics background and then the whole thing inevitably gets quite confusing because many (almost all, I really want to say) physicists are sloppy with the terminology, for example routinely use "continuous spectrum" (defined as $\sigma_{ac}\cup\sigma_{sc}$ for the mathematician) when they really mean the essential spectrum. Also, they often implicitly assume that essential spectrum always is ac spectrum, which is very wrong.

Comment: @ChristianRemling so, when physicists solve Schrödinger's equation $H\psi = E\psi$ to find the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian, what they have in mind is the characterization of the discrete and essential spectrum? Here I am using your definition of discrete spectrum, i.e. the isolated eigenvalues of finite multiplicity.